# Semantics of ">>" operator in F#

Tags: f#, operators, semantics

In Microsoft's [F# samples](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124614), they use the ">>" operator as follows:

```
test |> Seq.iter (any_to_string >> printfn "line %s");
```

What does the ">>" operator do in this context? Is each item of the sequence (an array in this case) get passed to `any_to_string` implicitly? Is this similar to `(fun item -> printfn "line %A" item)`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904049/in-f-what-does-the-operator-mean

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630940/what-is-the-name-of-in-f-and-what-does-it-do (for `|>` operator) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104618/what-does-mean-in-f (for `->` 'operator')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An equivalent piece of code could be written the following way:

```
test |> Seq.iter(fun x -> printfn "line %s" (any_to_string x))
```

In other words, the >> operator simply does this: given a function f(x) returning type T and g(y) with y being of type T, you can use f >> g to create a function h(z) being equivalent to g(f(x)). No argument but the inner and outer function has to be passed to that operator and the result is a function which can be applied at any time in your code, so you could do this:

```
//myFunc accepts any object, calls its ToString method, passes ToString
//result to the lambda which returns the string length. no argument is
//specified in advance
let myFunc = any_to_string >> (fun s -> s.Length)
let test = 12345
let f = 12345.0
//now we can call myFunc just like if we had definied it this way:
//let myFunc (x:obj) = obj.ToString().Length
printfn "%i" (myFunc i)
printfn "%i" (myFunc f)
```

Answer (score 8):

`(>>)` is a higher order function that takes two functions (with compatible arguments) and combines ("composes") them into one function.

For instance with

```
let len (s : string) = s.Length
let show (n : int) = n.ToString()
```

The line

```
(show >> len) 15
```

is equivalent to

```
len (show 15)
```

as well as

```
show 15 |> len
```

Answer (score 5):

The definition at

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/FSharp.Core/Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.html

says

```
val ( >> ) : ('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'c)
//Compose two functions, the function on the left being applied first
```

But I hope others will provide a more in-depth explanation.

EDIT

MSDN doc now at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353825(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Hmmm... It still seems like the argument is missing from the expression, but I guess it is implicitly the current item from the sequence. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Check out your more recent question about currying and partial application and it may make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's a function composition operator (as described in the other posts)

You can define this operator by yourself in order to see his semantics:

```
let (>>) f g = fun x -> g (f x)
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be no help at all if you are uncomfortable with C#, generics, or lambdas, but here is an equivalent in C#:

```
//Takes two functions, returns composed one
public static Func<T1, T2> Compose<T1, T2, T3>(this Func<T1, T2> f, Func<T2, T3> g)
{
    return (x) => g(f(x));
}
```

Looking at the type parameters reads something like Brian's answer:

Compose takes one function that goes from T1 to T2, and another that goes from T2 to T3, and returns the combination of the two, which goes from T1 to T3.

Answer (score 2):

The `>>` operator performs function composition, which is explained quite nicely [on Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Function_composition). Dustin Campbell provides a great use for it and explains it (along with the `|>` (forward pipe) operator) [on his blog](http://diditwith.net/2008/05/06/YAPESProblemSix.aspx).