# Understanding the F# Composition Operators

Tags: f#, pointfree, function-composition

I am well-versed in using the `>>` and `<<` operators in F#. However, after looking in the F# source to establish a deeper understanding I became confused with this:

```
let inline (>>) f g x = g(f x)
let inline (<<) f g x = f(g x)
```

How do I interpret these expressions conceptually? Also, how would you describe these expressions? Are they defining a type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [msdn page for F# functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx) says,

> Functions in F# can be composed from other functions. The composition of two functions `function1` and `function2` is another function that represents the application of `function1` followed the application of `function2`.

It can be thought of as similar to the pipe operators, just without specifying the last/deepest parameter; e.g. the following two lines are equivalent:

```
let composed = f >> g
let piped x = g <| f x
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904049/in-f-what-does-the-operator-mean) question for more information.

Comment: Before viewing the source, I would have imagined the `>>` operator to read like this: `let inline (>>) f g x = x(f g)`

Comment: But why? May seem like a strange question, but how would you put that code into sentence form?

Comment: Hmm... Not sure you can really put this type of function into sentence form the same way you can't do that with math sometimes. I suppose one way to describe it is that it allows you to rearrange the order functions appear in your code for better readability.

Comment: The question you referenced is what I was looking for (I guess I did not look hard enough before posting), to be specific: `Which reads as: given two functions, f and g, and a value, x, compute the result of f of x and pass that result to g. The interesting thing here is that you can curry the (>>) function and only pass in parameters f and g, the result is a function which takes a single parameter and produces the result g ( f ( x ) ).` Thank you for your help!

Comment: Am I missing something or did you type too fast and should you instead be defining `let piped x =` as `f1 x |> f2` (or `x |> f1 |> f2`) ? (Or did you mean that they are equivalent to the OPs cited inverse orderings?)

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to describe it is with an example, as looking at the definition can be a little confusing. Let's say you had this:

```
let isEven x = x % 2 = 0
[1 .. 99] |> List.filter (fun x -> not (isEven x))
```

Using the composition operators, you could rewrite it as one of these instead:

```
[1 .. 99] |> List.filter (isEven >> not)
[1 .. 99] |> List.filter (not << isEven)
```

More generically, if you have something like this:

```
data |> a |> b |> c
```

You can rewrite it like this:

```
data |> (a >> b >> c)
```

and interpret `a >> b >> c` as *do a, then do b, then do c*. If you prefer the more traditional backwards ordering:

```
(a (b (c data)))
```

you can rewrite it as

```
((a << b << c) data)
```

This is also called the point free style. In normal cases, it can be harder to read than using the normal style, but when passing to higher-order functions, it can be easier to read as you avoid having to add the `(fun x -> )` noise.