# Creating a negated predicate in F#

Tags: f#

I have a predicate in F# for example

```
let myFunc x y = x < y
```

Is there a way to create the negated version of this function?

So something that would be functionally similar to

```
let otherFunc x y = x >= y
```

But by using the original myFunc?

```
let otherFunc = !myFunc  // not valid
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called "function composition". Check out the function composition operator of f#:

- [In F# what does the >> operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904049/in-f-what-does-the-operator-mean)

I don't have a compiler available to experiment, but you could start from

```
let otherFunc = myFunc >> not
```

and work your way through errors.

**EDIT**: Max Malook points out that this will not work with the current definition of `myFunc`, because it takes two arguments (in a sense, this is functional-land). So, in order to make this work, `myFunc` would need to change into accepting a Tuple:

```
let myFunc (a, b) = a > b
let otherFunc = myFunc >> not
let what = otherFunc (3, 4)
```

Comment: It will only work when you provide the first argument.
    let otherFunc x = myFunc x >> not

Comment: @MaxMalook That depends on the function's type and the context. If the final type can be inferred, which is often the case in actual use cases, composition is valid. I would prefer function composition where it works, for brevity, and since additional named values take attention.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, and possibly amusement (if not clarity), one could also write `not << myFunc` to confuse your colleagues.

Answer (score 3):

Negation in F# is done with the function `not`. The `!` operator is for dereferencing `ref` cells.

```
let otherFunc x y = not (myFunc x y)
```