# What is the name of |> in F# and what does it do?

Tags: f#

A real F# noob question, but what is |> called and what does it do?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858989/semantics-of-operator-in-f (for `>>` operator) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104618/what-does-mean-in-f (for `->` 'operator')

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It's called the [forward pipe operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229(v=VS.100).aspx). It pipes the result of one function to another.**

The Forward pipe operator is simply defined as:

```
let (|>) x f = f x
```

And has a type signature:

```
'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b
```

Which resolves to: given a generic type 'a, and a function which takes an 'a and returns a 'b, then return the application of the function on the input.

You can read more detail about how it works in an [article here](http://srtsolutions.com/public/item/250478).

Comment: Thank you - for the life of me I couldnt remember its name

Comment: Guess that's one of the problems with custom operators, they're not googleable.

Comment: sure they are: "F# operators", you get the full list

Comment: It always blows me away that the implementation of such a powerful operator is so trivial.

Answer (score 8):

I usually refer to `|>` as the *pipelining operator*, but I'm not sure whether the official name is *pipe operator* or *pipelining operator* (though it probably doesn't really matter as the names are similar enough to avoid confusion :-)).

@LBushkin already gave a great answer, so I'll just add a couple of observations that may be also interesting. Obviously, the *pipelining operator* got it's name because it can be used for creating a pipeline that processes some data in several steps. The typical use is when working with lists:

```
[0 .. 10] 
  |> List.filter (fun n -> n % 3 = 0) // Get numbers divisible by three
  |> List.map (fun n -> n * n)        // Calculate squared of such numbers
```

This gives the result [0; 9; 36; 81]. Also, the operator is left-associative which means that the expression `input |> f |> g` is interpreted as `(input |> f) |> g`, which makes it possible to sequence multiple operations using `|>`.

Finally, I find it quite interesting that *pipelining operaor* in many cases corresponds to method chaining from object-oriented langauges. For example, the previous list processing example would look like this in C#:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10) 
  .Where(n => n % 3 == 0)    // Get numbers divisible by three
  .Select(n => n * n)        // Calculate squared of such numbers
```

This may give you some idea about when the operator can be used if you're comming fromt the object-oriented background (although it is used in many other situations in F#).

Answer (score 3):

As far as F# itself is concerned, the name is op_PipeRight (although no human would call it that).  I pronounce it "pipe", like the unix shell pipe.

The spec is useful for figuring out these kinds of things.  Section 4.1 has the operator names.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to check out the library reference docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754(v=VS.100).aspx

which list the operators.