# Project Euler 3 - Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes, pointfree, function-composition

I'm working my way through the Project Euler problems in Haskell. I have got a solution for Problem 3 below, I have tested it on small numbers and it works, however due to the brute force implementation by deriving all the primes numbers first it is exponentially slow for larger numbers.

```
-- Project Euler 3

module Main 
    where

import System.IO
import Data.List

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    putStrLn "This program returns the prime factors of a given integer"
    putStrLn "Please enter a number"
    nums <- getPrimes
    putStrLn "The prime factors are: "
    print (sort nums)


getPrimes = do
    userNum <- getLine
    let n = read userNum :: Int
    let xs = [2..n]
    return $ getFactors n (primeGen xs)

--primeGen :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
primeGen [] = []
primeGen (x:xs) = 
    if x >= 2
    then x:primeGen (filter (\n->n`mod` x/=0) xs)
    else 1:[2]

--getFactors
getFactors :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
getFactors n xs = [ x | x <- xs, n `mod` x == 0]
```

I have looked at the solution [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Euler_problems/1_to_10#Problem_3) and can see how it is optimised by the first guard in `factor`. What I dont understand is this:

```
primes = 2 : filter ((==1) . length . primeFactors) [3,5..]
```

Specifically the first argument of `filter`.

```
((==1) . length . primeFactors)
```

As primeFactors is itself a function I don't understand how it is used in this context. Could somebody explain what is happening here please?

Comment: Are you just having difficulty understanding the expression `primes = 2 : filter ((==1) . length . primeFactors) [3, 5 ..]`?

Comment: no, i understand what the expression itself does, its the first argument of filter that I don't understand ((==1) . length . primeFactors)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you were to open `ghci` on the command line and type

```
Prelude> :t filter
```

You would get an output of

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

What this means is that `filter` takes 2 arguments.

- `(a -> Bool)` is a function that takes a single input, and returns a `Bool`.
- `[a]` is a list of any type, as longs as it is the same type from the first argument.

`filter` will loop over every element in the list of its second argument, and apply it to the function that is its first argument. If the first argument returns `True`, it is added to the resulting list.

Again, in `ghci`, if you were to type

```
Prelude> :t (((==1) . length . primeFactors))
```

You should get

```
(((==1) . length . primeFactors)) :: a -> Bool
```

`(==1)` is a partially applied function.

```
Prelude> :t (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
Prelude> :t (==1)
(==1) :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
```

It only needs to take a single argument instead of two.

Meaning that together, it will take a single argument, and return a Boolean.

The way it works is as follows.

- `primeFactors` will take a single argument, and calculate the results, which is a `[Int]`.
- `length` will take this list, and calculate the length of the list, and return an `Int`
- `(==1)` will
  look to see if the values returned by `length` is equal to `1`.

If the length of the list is `1`, that means it is a prime number.

Comment: got it. What was throwing me off is that I was expecting an argument to primeFactors within the brackets. Then after I remebered that filter cycles through [3,5..]. The recursive call returns a list of factors, to which the partial fucntion is applied, consing only lists with a length of 1 , i.e prime numbers. Hope that makes sense to everybody, I understand it now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help you understand.

Answer (score 3):

`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` is the composition function, so

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

We can chain more than two functions together with this operator

```
f . g . h  ===  \x -> f (g (h x))
```

This is what is happening in the expression `((==1) . length . primeFactors)`.

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
filter ((==1) . length . primeFactors) [3,5..]
```

is filtering the list `[3, 5..]` using the function `(==1) . length . primeFactors`.  This notation is usually called *point free*, not because it doesn't have `.` points, but because it doesn't have any explicit arguments (called "points" in some mathematical contexts).

The `.` is actually a function, and in particular it performs function composition.  If you have two functions `f` and `g`, then `f . g = \x -> f (g x)`, that's all there is to it!  The precedence of this operator lets you chain together many functions quite smoothly, so if you have `f . g . h`, this is the same as `\x -> f (g (h x))`.  When you have many functions to chain together, the composition operator is very useful.

So in this case, you have the functions `(==1)`, `length`, and `primeFactors` being compose together.  `(==1)` is a function through what is called *operator sections*, meaning that you provide an argument to one side of an operator, and it results in a function that takes one argument and applies it to the other side.  Other examples and their equivalent lambda forms are

```
(+1)           =>  \x -> x + 1
(==1)          =>  \x -> x == 1
(++"world")    =>  \x -> x ++ "world"
("hello"++)    =>  \x -> "hello" ++ x
```

If you wanted, you could re-write this expression using a lambda:

```
(==1) . length . primeFactors => (\x0 -> x0 == 1) . length . primeFactors
                              => (\x1 -> (\x0 -> x0 == 1) (length (primeFactors x1)))
```

Or a bit cleaner using the `$` operator:

```
(\x1 -> (\x0 -> x0 == 1) $ length $ primeFactors x1)
```

But this is still a lot more "wordy" than simply

```
(==1) . length . primeFactors
```

---

One thing to keep in mind is the type signature for `.`:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

But I think it looks better with some extra parentheses:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

This makes it more clear that this function takes two other functions and returns a third one.  Pay close attention the the order of the type variables in this function.  The first argument to `.` is a function `(b -> c)`, and the second is a function `(a -> b)`.  You can think of it as going right to left, rather than the left to right behavior that we're used to in most OOP languages (something like `myObj.someProperty.getSomeList().length()`).  We can get this functionality by defining a new operator that has the reverse order of arguments.  If we use the F# convention, our operator is called `|>`:

```
(|>) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
(|>) = flip (.)
```

Then we could have written this as

```
filter (primeFactors |> length |> (==1)) [3, 5..]
```

And you can think of `|>` as an arrow "feeding" the result of one function into the next.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've only just seen it after accepting one of the others above. Both made it very clear and both very helpful so +1.

Comment: @Dave0504 whichever one makes it most clear is the one to accept, I'm just glad I could help :)

Comment: in F#, [`(|>) x f = f x`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2630957/849891). it is left-associative. `flip (.)` in F# [is called `( >> )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353825%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This simply means, keep only the odd numbers that have only one prime factor.

In other pseodo-code: `filter(x -> length(primeFactors(x)) == 1) for any x in [3,5,..]`