# Are . and -> in C and C++ really operators?

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages, operators

you probably have been tought, are tought yourselves, that . and -> are **operators** which retrieve members of a struct (C) or class (C++).

However, I doubt they are operators - because, if they are operators, what are their input types? Furthermore, the identifiers on both sides are interdependent - a feature which for example the + operator lacks of.

If this is correct - in what sense are these still labeled as operator in practice, and what is their formal definition with regard to language theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reference says they're both operators in C++:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Is that not authoritative enough?

Comment: Thanks, it is. The same question could have been stated for e.g. type-castings, scope resolutions, which the standard regards as operators. Nevertheless, I remain uncomfortable with operators that do not have a function prototype in general.

Comment: See also the last paragraph of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104618/what-does-mean-in-f/105559#105559

Comment: As I said in another comment - appeal to authority is a widely recognised invalid argument. It is possible that the C++ standards committee and those involved in defining the language chose their words badly. In this case they didn't, but there's still room to explain *why* the wording is appropriate, instead of just saying "such-and-such says so".

Comment: @Steve314: Well, it's an operator in the sense that it does something - namely, they access a member in whatever is on the left hand side.

Comment: I would agree that there might still be room for explanation.  I don't agree that your answer is doing it for me personally.  But at least my answer does address "Are they *really* operators?".  The answer is "yes".  And I'll point out that, at least for now, it was accepted by the OP.  It seems good enough for him/her.  "To put it another way - if you didn't call it an operator, what would you call it?" - is this your idea of a superior argument?

Comment: @Steve314: No, appeal to authority is only an invalid argument when you're appealing to an authority that doesn't actually *define the answer*. The C++ standard defines what is and is not an operator in the C++ language, *regardless* of what an operator is or means elsewhere.

Comment: @jalf - The C++ standard defines the C++ programming language. When we talk about `->` being an operator, we are using the English language, which is not defined by the C++ standard. When we talk about the use of the function `operator->` we are again describing the C++ language, but that still doesn't mean that the people who defined the C++ language and standard can't have chosen their words badly. Any written text - including the C++ standard - has the purpose of communicating, and should (but may not) respect existing definitions of the terms it uses for that reason.

Comment: @Steve314: The term *operator* means something specific in C++.  Consequently, the only way to tell if something is an operator in C++ is to look at the definition, which in this case is the standard. This isn't an appeal to authority—which is indeed a fallacy—but is instead "appeal to definition", which is tautologically true.  You might argue that the authors of the spec should have chosen another term (though I'd disagree), but the most you can then say is "C++ defines *operator* badly". (Appeal to authority would apply if you then argued from this that *operator* meant the same elsewhere.)

Comment: @Antal - of course it's true that any substantial document needs its own specific definitions of jargon. That's fine. But the question here specifically references formal definitions in programming theory, which aren't invalidated just because we're talking about a specific language that is defined by a specific document with some specific jargon. For some questions, an appeal to the standard is perfectly valid, but IMO in this case it is pointless. Better to explain *why* the choice of words wasn't a bad or misleading.

Comment: @Antal - BTW, picking up on your implication - I never said the choice of the word "operator" was a bad one either. In fact, I said the exact opposite. I simply think there is something potentially interesting to say about *why* it's a perfectly good choice.

Comment: @duffymo: while appealing to authority is good in itself, I would certainly not claim that `www.cplusplus.com` is such an authority... I would rather have used either the Standard itself, or "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroupstrup.

Comment: Is the information they supplied incorrect?  And I disagree with your point - argument from authority is one of the no-no's of debate.  But the crucial difference is when you say "because *I* said so" or "because god said so".  In this case we're citing the language standard itself, which is a completely different matter.

Comment: @Steve314: I missed the part about language theory; in that context, you're right, the jargon term isn't a sufficient explanation.

Comment: This is some of the most pretentious noise I've read here.  There's a good reason why SO tries to be about answers and not useless discussions like this one.  "...Think of a man working at a machine..." - is this truly your idea of "programming theory"?

Comment: @duffymo - on "what would you call it?" the point is there's only so many words, and only so much value in trying to avoid a conflict of meanings. On "Think of a man...", no it's not my idea of "programming theory". On your tone - I haven't chosen my words carefully enough to complain about that, and besides, I do tend to be long-winded and to end up seeming pretentious. Sorry if it bugged you.

Comment: Lots of cycles wasted on a question like "are these operators in C++?".  It feels much more black and white to me.  This discussion is misplaced, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

You assume that the only types which can be passed as arguments to an operator are types that can be defined within the language.

I would argue that any type which can be recognised by the compiler may be passed as an argument, including internal types such as "identifier". The operator will have two arguments in its AST representation, which is enough to allow you to define semantics.

Another argument is that language theory may provide one set of definitions for your vocabulary, but it isn't the only one.

For example, an operator may be a man who works a machine. That definition has no relevance to programming theory, but it won't stop me using for keywords in a domain-specific language expressing something to do with machine operating. Similarly, the term "operator" has a wider definition in mathematics than that which is specific to programming theory - and that definition isn't invalidated simply by working with a programming language.

To put it another way - if you didn't call it an operator, what *would* you call it?

**EDIT**

To clarify, my first argument is referring to the syntax for using the operator (the call). These operators have right arguments which are identifiers - member names - which the C++ language cannot express using a data type. The C++ language *does* have member pointers, but they aren't the same thing as the members - just as a variable isn't the same as a pointer to that variable.

I assume that is what the question referred to. The right parameter of those operators has a type which cannot be expressed or manipulated normally in the language.

What happens when that syntax is mapped to an overloaded `operator->` function is a different thing. The function isn't the operator - it's only how the operator gets implemented.

Answer (score 5):

I think the fact that you can overload the `->` operator using the "operator" keyword should be a dead giveaway.

Smart pointers do it pretty often:

```
template<class T>
struct myPtr {
    T *operator ->()    { return m_ptr; }

    private:
        T *m_ptr;
};
```

The `.` is not overloadable, but is also an operator by definition.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm...`sizeof` is an operator, what is its input type? I don't think the question is useful for distinguishing operators from non-operators in this context.

And *that* would be because what "operator" means in the context of a programming language is *exactly* what the author of the language *says* it means. Shades of Lewis Carroll here.

Comment: In programming theory terms, of course, sizeof is more likely to be considered a function. Acting at compile-time rather than run-time is besides the point. Being a compiler-intrinsic rather than a user/library function is besides the point. And the fact that the argument type is "datatype" - a type that you can't pass as a parameter to your own functions - is also besides the point, whether sizeof is a function or an operator. The standards and jargon of C and C++ give alternate definitions with their own history, but even Lewis Carroll was making a Cratylus-related joke.

Comment: BTW - I still gave you +1 for the Lewis Carroll reference. Very relevant to the little disagreement I'm having.

Comment: @Steve314: Such a definition of a "function" (that encompasses `sizeof`) would seem to be little different from that of an operator - the `+` operator could equally be called a "function".

Comment: @caf - the + operator is syntactically infix. You can have prefix operators, of course, but once you start spelling them alphabetically the usual term (excepting specific C/C++ jargon) tends to be "function". In the sizeof case, you even have the compulsory parens, which (in a vague definitely-not-what-Church-said sense) tends to suggest a function.

Comment: @Steve314: The parantheses with `sizeof` are only required if it is to operate on a type name - given `int array[10];`, then `sizeof array` is perfectly valid.  It seems a little specious to define the difference between an operator and a function to come down to whether it is spelt out using alphabetical characters or not.

Comment: @caf - yes, but subjectivity is the price you pay for using a subjective language, and having odd and inconsistent distinctions from historic and other reasons comes naturally too. Normally a good reason to specify objective context-specific definitions, as standards documents do - but when you dealing with multiple contexts, it is only natural that your language will tend to end up either being subjective and vague, or pedantic, long-winded and confusing, or a bit of both - and either way being oddly inconsistent too. IOW - don't blame me, blame everyone else ;-)

Comment: @caf - confession - I didn't know the sizeof parens weren't always needed. In that case, it starts to look more like a prefix operator - though I believe in the theory there's a view that says any function has precisely one n-tuple argument where n can even be zero.

Comment: @Steve: I'm a little weak on the classical education front: had to look up Cratylus. Bloody Greeks! Stealing all our sophomore bullshitting session two millennia before we have them! Any way, perhaps the committee made a mistake, but for the purposes of communicating with other c and c++ programmers it just doesn't matter.

Comment: @dmckdee - I only found out about Cratylus googling the quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the -> operator: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B). That page also states that you can't overload dot. There's an example of -> overloading [here](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2005_10_09_archive.html):

```
class String // this is handle
{
  ...
  Stringrep *operator -> () const { return b_; }
  private:
  Stringrep *b_;
}
```

The arrow works on the value to the left of the arrow and returns whatever the left hand side is "holding inside". Think of a [smart pointer](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading#Address_of.2C_Reference.2C_and_Pointer_operators).

Answer (score 1):

THe C++03 standard refers to both as operators.

Example:

> ...after the . operator applied to an expression of the type of its class...

If you are not comfortable with that terminology you can use the term punctuator for `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Online C standard ([n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)):

> **6.5.2.3 Structure and union members**
> **Constraints**
> 1 The first operand of the `.` operator shall have a qualified or unqualified structure or union
> type, and the second operand shall name a member of that type.
> 2 The first operand of the `->` operator shall have type ‘‘pointer to qualified or unqualified
> structure’’ or ‘‘pointer to qualified or unqualified union’’, and the second operand shall
> name a member of the type pointed to.

They are operators, and their input types are specified by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

haha, i know people have already said this in a roundabout way but just to say it directly. In C terms, label-> is actually a shorthand for (*label). .That being said, . is the operator which references elements in a struct. Therefore, -> references an element in a pointer to a struct.

Comment: In C terms yes, but the tags include C++. When overloading, there is an `operator->` separate from `operator*`, so the "shorthand" argument doesn't necessarily apply. That said, it is still good practice to ensure that the shorthand effectively applies - if you overload `operator->` and `operator*`, you should overload them consistently (and with the expected pointer-like semantics in mind).

Comment: true, i was speaking in c terms. however, i do consider overloading -> in c++ to be very bad practice.

Comment: I agree, really. There's some inconsistencies that occur because smart pointers and iterators usually only implement operator*. If -> was just a shorthand - always available when it made sense, and not needing operator-> - it would avoid a few hassles.