# Help me understand lambda expression precedence

Tags: f#, operator-precedence

Looking at the [Operator Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) table, I'm confused by where lambda expressions fit in to all of this. Numbering the table 1 to 25 (lowest to highest precedence), I see the two key tokens used for composing lambda expressions: `fun` is non-associative 6, and `->` is right-associative 8. That is, `fun ... -> ...`. This might be my first mistake in understanding, since I'm not even sure if precedence plays a role in the body of a lambda expression (the right hand side of `->`) I can only think of precedence playing a role in the entire expression, so I'll move on to there. According to this table, the sequence operator, `;`, has lower precedence, 4, than the `fun` "operator". Which I believe says that

```
fun (x:int) -> x + 3 ; 2;;
```

should be equivalent to

```
((fun (x:int) -> (x + 3)) ; 2);;
```

yet it is actually equivalent to

```
(fun (x:int) -> (x + 3 ; 2));;
```

I appreciate any help clarifying my interpretation of the rules of precedence given by the referenced table vs. the actual rules of precedence for lambda expressions! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

MU

(If you are reading an operator precedence table, you've already lost.  The table probably has bugs, but who cares, don't read the table.  And don't use the sequence operator (`;`).  And if you do use the sequence operator next to a lambda, then put the lambda in parentheses.  Or just put every lambda in parentheses.  I touch the code for the F# parser all the time, and I have no clue what the relative precedence of `;` versus `fun` versus `->` is, I don't even know what it means for `->` to have a precedence (it is [not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104618/what-does-mean-in-f/105559#105559) in expressions (only in types, where it is indeed right-associative)...  I cannot imagine any satisfying answer to this question or any followup.  You should have no interest in any of this unless you're writing your own parser/compiler for F#.  These are not the droids you're looking for.)

Comment: Haha, I knew the table was no good (and the Spec isn't much more helpful)! But I do have a very good reason for both using the sequence operator and obtaining a deep understanding the precedence rules ;). Would looking at the F# parser help at all, or would someone mostly unfamiliar with fslex / fsyacc just be totally lost? Any other suggestions for getting a grip on the precedence rules? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I don't know what "MU" stands for!

Comment: as you nearly guessed, I am interested in all of this because I am working on a quotation decompiler as part of a larger open source project Unquote (http://code.google.com/p/unquote/). The lack of a complete precedence specification is slowing me down, is this something I should file a Spec bug for using fsbugs@microsoft.com?