# F# Seq.fold intellisense

Tags: syntax, f#, extension-methods

I'm learning F# and am struggling to parse the intellisense that appears for `Seq.fold`:

```
val fold : ('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> seq<'T> -> 'State
```

In C# I'm accustomed to the `Aggregate` extension method and can understand perfectly fine the C# declaration:

```
(extension) TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func);
```

So in order to understand/deduce the F# syntax in this case, I've been trying to establish an analogy between `Seq.fold` and `Aggregate` but perhaps this is the wrong approach. I understand that `->` defines a function (or the signature?), but beyond that I'm having a hard time reading what appeared.

To be clear, I don't need an example of how to use folding; I'm simply looking for a breakdown of the the F# syntax used in the `Seq.fold` intellisense. Thanks.

Comment: Related question which might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104618/what-does-mean-in-f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F# and many other functional languages, `'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd` is the type of function which takes parameters of type `'a`, `'b`, `'c` as input*, and returns a `'d`. So

```ml
  ('State -> 'T -> 'State)
//  1st      2nd   output
```

means, in C#, a function of type

```cs
State func<State,T>(State firstInput, T secondInput);
```

and

```ml
  ('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> seq<'T> -> 'State
//1st input (a function)      2nd       3rd        output
```

means, in C#, a function of type

```cs
State func<State,T>(Func<State, T, State> firstInput,
                    State secondInput, 
                    IEnumerable<T> thirdInput);
```

<sub>*: currying is ignored for the moment.</sub>

Comment: and `firstInput` is `func`, and `secondInput` is `seed`, and `thirdInput` is `source` in the C# `Aggregate` analogy

Answer (score 1):

fold is a function which accepts a function ( fun ) taking a element of type 'State and element of type T and returning value of type 'State ( `('State -> 'T -> 'State)` ), a value of type 'State and a sequence of elements of type T and returns a value of type `State

Basically, type the following in the F# interactive

```
let sum x y = x+y;;
```

and you will see

```
val sum : int -> int -> int
```

That means sum take int and int and return an int. If you can understand this, you can understand any function signature.

Also note that -> is right associative and the notation will become more apparent when you see functions as transformations accepting one value and transforming it in to another.

So the above is actually int -> (int -> int ) a function taking int and returning a function which takes a int and returns int ( referred to as currying. )